# Where does Qt Creator save its settings?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I would like to locate the folder where Qt Creator saves all its settings (text editor preferences, syntax highlighting, etc.) so that I can back them up. Does anybody know where they are?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

See [QtCreator Quick Tour](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-quick-tour.html#location-of-settings-files).

> Qt Creator creates the following files and directories:
>
> ```
> QtCreator.db
> QtCreator.ini
> qtversion.xml
> toolChains.xml
> qtcreator
> qtc-debugging-helper
> qtc-qmldump
> ```
>
> The location depends on the platform. On Linux and other Unix
>   platforms, the files are located in `~/.config/QtProject` and
>   `~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator`.
>
> On Mac OS, the files are located in `~/.config/QtProject` and
>   `~/Library/Application Support/QtProject/Qt Creator`.

On Windows in general, the files are located in `%APPDATA%\QtProject` and `%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtProject`. Yes, you can use these paths in Explorer and in various command line shells. The environment variables (between the `%`-signs) are expanded automatically. If you need the concrete paths, see below.

> On Windows 10, 8, Vista and 7, the files are located in
>   `<drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject` and
>   `<drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\QtProject`.
>
> On Windows XP, the files are located in `<drive>:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Application Data\QtProject` and `<drive>:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\QtProject`.

Comment: One additional note (years later):  if QT creator is running really really slowly (read: 100% cpu) this could resolve that.  I had this problem with a centos VM, and deleting these files fixed it.

Comment: Should we delete those two folders to make Qt Creator settings reset?

Comment: Another note: there are two copies of XML files in `$CREATOR_INSTALL_DIR/share/QtProject/qtcreator` and in `%APPDATA%/QtProject/qtcreator`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986917/2404492. The first fileset is created by `sdktool` and QtCreator copies it to the second one, appending manually added data.

Answer (score 13):

Starting from version 2.7 it's `%APPDATA%/Roaming/QtProject` on Windows 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Bill's answer, Qt Creator might also create files in `\QtCreator\bin\` - this is where it's going to save all your projects by default.

Comment: `\QtCreator\bin\ ` is not a valid path on any major OS. You're using forward slashes, so I assume you're on Windows. Is this relative to the home directory (`%HOMEPATH%\QtCreator\bin\ `) or to the system drive (`%SYSTEMDRIVE%\QtCreator\bin\ `) or to the Qt installation directory ? Please consider completing your answer.