# Where does QtCreator store data about Kits?

Tags: qt-creator

For a particular project, QtCreator stores information about the build configurations for each [kit](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html) that project uses in its `*.creator.user` file. Some kits are automatically detected; kits can also be manually defined by going to `Options-->Build & Run-->Kits` and selecting `Add`. However, I can't figure out where QtCreator actually stores information about available kits. Deleting all `*.creator.user` files that make use of a particular kit does not remove the kit from the list of kits, and I can't find the names of any custom kits I've defined anywhere in the Qt folder on my computer (I'm using Qt5 RC2, so I'm looking in `Qt5/QtCommercial5.0.0-rc2/Tools/QtCreator/share` and subdirectories thereof). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The SDK stores a set of files in `$CREATOR_INSTALL_DIR/share/QtProject/qtcreator`. These are used by everybody using this instance of creator.

The user-specific files are in your home directory in `~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator` (or `%APPDATA%/QtProject/qtcreator` on windows, don't know about Mac).

The kits are in a file called `profiles.xml` (I first called this whole thing profiles, but since that conflicts with the `.pro`-files `qmake` uses it got renamed). Toolchains are in `toolchains.xml`, Qt versions in `qtversions.xml`.

The `.user`-files only contain data for the project it is related to. Basically everything set in "Projects" mode ends up in the `.user` file.

Comment: Thank you! Is this the only place that kit information is stored, though? I only see the auto-detected kit there, but I still see other kits (that I thought would be deleted by deleting my `.user` file) in the project view.

Comment: Yes, these are the only two places. The SDK writes its config files into the Qt creator installation directory and creator then later copies those into the user files in your home directory and adds your manually configured kits there.

Comment: @TobiasHunger conflict? in speech you mean? you wrote this? cheers!

Comment: btw. I'm looking for a `PE.Profile.Name` with `cpp` is it from trolltech? I don't know how it came to be I only have `Desktop` here.

Comment: Saved my day! Just removed the settings folder to run QtCreator as a fresh copy.

Comment: As of late 2021, you can find SDK files under ```$CREATOR_INSTALL_DIR/share/qtcreator/QtProject```