# Qt Creator Clang Code Model can't find included header in included header

Tags: c++, qt, clang, qt-creator

My problem  is as follow:
The clang code model from Qt Creator is unable to find the first header included in the header file of a cpp file.

CPP-File:

[image: cpp file]

Header file of that cpp-file:

[image: header file]

As you can see, the code model has no issues finding QDialog in the header file, but has so in the cpp file. I have the same issue in other files too. The project compiles without problems too.
I already deleted the cache files in my build folder and reindexed all again. I can't find the log files of clang tho.

Comment: Do you have this in your cmake file?

Comment: Yes, I do. The program compiles without any errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabling unity build fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `clandg` code model gets lost when updating QtCreator or changing its compiler settings. Last time

1. Removing `%APPDATA%\QtProject`
2. Removing `%LOCALAPPDATA%\QtProject`
3. Re-creating the project from scratch

has fixed the problem for me.

(The paths above are for Windows. For other platforms see [Where QtCreator stores its settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743019) and [kits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13986917))