# Have same qtcreator settings on different computer/OS

Tags: settings, qt-creator

I have to use Qt Creator on many computers, and I would want to copy all my settings to them. If all are on linux, it's quite easy because I generally copy my home... but I didn't find any way to do it to windows...
Thanks !

Comment: It's possible to export the c++ code formatter settings easyly but I search to get the same syntax highlighter, same shortcuts etc. too

Comment: This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742663/where-does-qtcreator-save-its-settings) and its answers might help you.