# How to restore default kits in Qt Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I deleted all the default kits from Qt Creator and I don't know how to get them back. In other words, how can I restore all the default kits in Qt Creator?

I tried to delete all the Qt files from my Ubuntu System, the whole Qt folder, the `~/.config/QtProject` folder and all qt packages. After reinstalling Qt, all the old kits are still there, instead of the default ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delete the `~/.config/QtProject` and `~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator` directories:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/QtProject ~/.local/share/data/QtProject/qtcreator
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742663/where-does-qtcreator-save-its-settings).