# A new Qt widget application will not compile

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I am relatively new to Qt and was going through many tutorials. Everything was fine. All scripts compiled and ran. 
Then, at some point, I am getting the error for even a new Qt widget application created with Qt Creator 4.3.1:

```
C:\  \Documents\111\main.cpp:-1: In function 'int qMain(int, char**)':
C:\   \Documents\111\main.cpp:6: error: variable 'QApplication a' has initializer but incomplete type
     QApplication a(argc, argv);
                    ^
C:\   \Documents\111\main.cpp:11: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
```

I am not sure what happened, yet seems like some setups were messed up.
`QApplication` is included, and not missing in the script.

```
111.pro
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-02-23T01:36:28
QT       += core gui
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = 111
TEMPLATE = app
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
    mainwindow.ui

main.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

return a.exec();
}

mainview.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
delete ui;
}
```

It seems to me that this issue appeared after trying to run `qt5.6_src.zip` examples from https://en.ids-imaging.com/open-source.html.

Comment: First, please take the [tour]. Second, show the code that leads to the error message; don't dump the complete project but make it a [mcve] including the `.pro` file.

Comment: @NikosC. Do you think this makes a difference? Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed by deleting the `Qt` folder and `QtCreator` folder in the `<drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\QtProject` and `<drive>:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Qt`. It stored incorrect settings, which I somehow setup by running open source scripts. For more information visit [Where does QtCreator save its settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742663/where-does-qtcreator-save-its-settings).

Answer (score 1):

Without completed code, I guess you need to add `#include <QApplication>` to `main.cpp`

The error message told you what is missing.

Comment: Thanks @Jiu. The problem is that the `#include <QApplication> ` is there in `main.cpp`. But the code does not compile with the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Qt's docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html), the constructor's signature is `QApplication(int &argc, char **argv)`.
Therefore, if you inherit from `QApplication` then the subclass's constructor must pass `argc` by reference.    From your description, it appears that the constructor of your subclass is actually passing `argc` by value (i.e., `int qMain(int, char**)` ).  That will cause some problems.