# Can't run android app in QtCreator

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator

I am trying to run Android app in Qt-Creator .when i try to build it , it builds without any problems but when I hit run button , instead of asking where to run app it gives me this error :-

```
Cannot find the android build step.
Error while building/deploying project untitled (kit: Android for armeabi-v7a (GCC 4.9, Qt  (android_armv7)))
When executing step "Deploy to Android device"
```

I am using Arch Linux . I had install Android SDK and NDK and OracleJDK 10.
I had connected my Karbon Titanium phone via USB to my laptop and enabled the USB DEBUGGING .

EDIT:-

Here are environment variables:-

```
% cat /etc/environment 
#
# This file is parsed by pam_env module
#
# Syntax: simple "KEY=VAL" pairs on separate lines
#
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default
JRE_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime

PATH=/home/jimbo/bin:/home/jimbo/.local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/opt/cordova/bin:/opt/AndroidSDK/tools/bin

RUSTUP_HOME=/opt/Rust
CARGO_HOME=/opt/Rust/.cargo
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/AndroidSDK
ANDROID_NDK_HOME=/opt/AndroidNDK
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/bin/pkg-config
```

Also I am using NDK 10e:-

[image]

Comment: Do you have emulator or connected device ??

Comment: What version of NDK and SDK are you using?

Comment: @eyllanesc    SDK version =  26.1.1 and NDK version = r17-linux-x86_64

Comment: @MohammadKanan I have my android phone connected

Comment: @noone 
The problem is in the NDK, I'm also an archilinux user and the problem is that the NDK version is not supported by Qt, according to the docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/androidgs.html informs that it supports the version 10e version, if you have installed aur you can install aur/android-ndk-10e

Comment: Or download it from https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64.zip

Comment: @eyllanesc Sory for late reply ,But still after downloading 1GB old NDK , I am getting the same warning.

Comment: have you changed the route of the NDK in Qt? 
I recommend downloading it from aur, this will place that NDK in the Path by default, most likely the script compiling Qt is pointing to the other NDK.

Comment: @eyllanesc pls see my edit. Also , do I have to set PATH variable for NDK ? if yes , then where ? there are just too many bin folders .

Comment: @noone 
I think the easiest thing is to install it from aur: `yaourt -S aur/android-ndk-10e` and then  `yaourt -S android-qt5-armeabi-v7a`

Answer (score 1):

> you have to use Qt version `5.9.0` with `sdk 26.1.1` and `ndk version 10.4.0`.
>   earlier version than `5.9.0` of qt will not work with `sdk 26.1.1`.
>   so you just need to update your Qt version to `5.9.0`.

At Last, Use This Combination:

```
Jdk version : 1.8.0
SDK version : 26.1.1
NDK version : 10.4.0
Qt version : 5.9.0
```

it works for me. hope it will work for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

Just delete Qt creator settings files and restart it:

[Where does QtCreator save its settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742663/where-does-qtcreator-save-its-settings)

> On Windows 10, 8, Vista and 7, the files are located in
>   :\Users\\AppData\Roaming\QtProject and 
>   :\Users\\AppData\Local\QtProject.
>
> On Windows XP, the files are located in :\Documents and
>   Settings\\Application Data\QtProject and :\Documents
>   and Settings\\Local Settings\Application Data\QtProject.

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-20088

> A problem was solved when I re-created the QtC settings from scratch.
>
> So, something wrong in QtC code, related to the settings update,
>   because, as can see from my screenshoots, the QtC reported that all
>   Android configuration is OK, but the build step was not created.